# SSL handshake keeps failing even after adding certificates to local truststore Ubuntu VM

Tags: linux, virtualbox, ssl, openssl, trusted-root-certificates

When executing

```
wget https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/4.6.0/_downloads/52a95608c49671267e40c689e0bc00ca/conda-cheatsheet.pdf
```

I have this error:

```
--2020-06-03 20:55:06--  https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/4.6.0/_downloads/52a95608c49671267e40c689e0bc00ca/conda-cheatsheet.pdf
Resolving docs.conda.io (docs.conda.io)... 104.31.71.166, 104.31.70.166, 172.67.149.185, ...
Connecting to docs.conda.io (docs.conda.io)|104.31.71.166|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify docs.conda.io's certificate, issued by ‘CN=SSL-SG1-GFRPA2,OU=Operations,O=Cloud Services,C=US’:
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to docs.conda.io insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
```

The certificates chain in the URL above contains 4 certificates.

What I have tried to solve this problem:

0) Extract the 4 certificates in the chain, from chrome when opening the url

1) Just to ensure not missing certificates, I put all the 4 certificates (namely `conda1.crt`, `conda2.crt`, `conda3.crt`, `conda4.crt`) in `/usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/` by doing `sudo cp conda*.crt /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/`

2) `sudo vi /etc/ca-certificates.conf` and append `mozilla/conda1.crt`, `mozilla/conda2.crt`, `mozilla/conda3.crt`, `mozilla/conda4.crt` at the end

3) run `sudo update-ca-certificates -f`

4) I can see symbolic link created under /etc/ssl/certs which looks like: `conda1.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/conda1.crt`, `conda2.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/conda2.crt`, etc.

Verification:

```
openssl verify -no-CAfile -no-CApath -partial_chain -CAfile conda1.pem conda2.pem
conda2.pem: OK

openssl verify -no-CAfile -no-CApath -partial_chain -CAfile conda2.pem conda3.pem
conda3.pem: OK

openssl verify -no-CAfile -no-CApath -partial_chain -CAfile conda3.pem conda4.pem
conda4.pem: OK
```

Result: still fail with wget

**P.S.**
I am facing this ssl problem in many aspects and many urls since a month ago (no problem before):

1. I cannot do conda search a_package
2. I cannot do requests.get(url) in python code
3. I cannot open it in a browser within my ubuntu system (can only access in windows)
4. I cannot do fromUrl in scala

It seems the problem is not only due to one or two certificates, instead, it's a systematic problem in my ubuntu system. Looks like it's missing a list of certificates in my truststore.

`uname` => Linux user 5.3.0-53-generic #47~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 7 13:10:50 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I'm using Oracle VirtualBox.

**UPDATE1**

For conda1.crt:

```
openssl x509 -noout -text < conda1.crt
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            1b:b7:86:d3:b6:ad:8f:65:b9:7a:79:3e:c7:48:84:27
        Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = US, O = "BlueCoat Systems, Inc.", CN = Cloud Services Root CA
        Validity
            Not Before: Sep  6 00:00:00 2011 GMT
            Not After : Sep  5 23:59:59 2021 GMT
        Subject: C = US, O = "BlueCoat Systems, Inc.", CN = Cloud Services Root CA
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                RSA Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:c4:00:7b:f6:a2:29:37:43:40:a5:44:b4:6d:ed:
                    0d:15:80:ea:9d:8d:e0:f6:32:6c:61:9e:87:55:1b:
                    1b:c3:67:89:9c:ed:81:29:88:68:04:e5:b9:7e:65:
                    1c:f4:56:93:d1:56:e1:22:89:07:15:18:f8:c3:77:
                    36:91:e5:95:81:39:45:1d:ba:7a:11:96:9a:2b:51:
                    fc:c9:cc:d3:7f:9e:d6:95:72:0b:b8:2a:c9:f5:e1:
                    98:b1:61:36:76:82:5e:3e:71:69:4f:54:1e:8c:34:
                    50:60:c2:93:8c:07:d0:03:4b:70:08:14:b1:c6:66:
                    79:4f:31:09:ff:10:2e:e1:c6:13:73:70:a7:32:b8:
                    00:de:7f:bf:b5:c1:fb:62:7e:4f:0c:d1:80:8b:06:
                    4c:59:fe:4e:3d:b9:2d:1f:7d:db:da:be:f2:7b:1f:
                    9b:81:75:e2:bd:8d:4c:c3:a9:3c:d9:16:0b:4c:b4:
                    6c:6b:c0:28:96:e0:43:4e:99:6a:31:b1:e8:d5:01:
                    3b:02:eb:de:78:59:0b:2f:91:97:5f:ff:14:c5:aa:
                    34:98:1b:ee:77:63:49:08:74:d9:f4:47:32:1e:7e:
                    7f:63:68:27:a8:95:b8:b6:66:cc:35:7a:eb:84:01:
                    3e:e5:8d:5d:58:c0:14:f1:01:52:17:46:ac:cd:04:
                    04:db
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
                DirName:/CN=MPKI-2048-1-99
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
                A6:4A:17:D1:BC:58:B5:77:25:16:92:2B:D2:4C:95:23:CF:28:14:36
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
         8c:f8:95:4c:29:f3:4d:4c:a0:32:dc:68:0e:9e:83:03:26:a6:
         a6:66:07:1d:bc:ef:0f:89:d7:60:df:77:ce:7b:a0:1d:e8:76:
         ac:e6:02:86:4d:cc:4a:d1:ff:73:64:68:cb:15:f7:84:f4:fc:
         df:5c:d0:eb:9c:ca:f9:06:76:97:b9:1c:da:33:a0:38:b6:2c:
         78:89:d0:12:35:19:cc:4c:1e:78:03:4d:f8:31:dd:33:8b:69:
         a8:69:52:c7:34:2f:20:33:2d:53:c2:f4:ff:5f:c2:98:19:fb:
         ca:19:1f:7a:4c:84:c6:9c:7d:18:03:59:8f:a1:9a:bc:dd:64:
         fe:cc:7e:16:7b:59:73:e6:64:a0:60:cf:38:64:f7:4f:33:fd:
         9d:86:8e:5f:78:cd:09:ba:31:a1:06:24:d3:af:cb:fd:df:ba:
         c6:ac:84:37:b1:61:2a:32:02:48:59:66:4b:27:f1:9e:bf:1f:
         9a:45:a4:0d:48:42:42:d7:13:f8:55:7a:33:2c:a7:6c:5e:ba:
         b6:27:8f:5f:72:0a:45:aa:24:bc:a1:d5:f6:68:30:c4:9f:01:
         5d:c3:a5:c0:4c:0e:93:0f:f1:4d:e2:cb:41:e0:76:97:6e:f8:
         ac:f9:1d:9b:06:8f:e6:a9:c7:dd:df:73:57:37:c6:f8:8d:bc:
         07:01:ff:ad
```

For conda4.crt:

```
openssl x509 -noout -text < conda4.crt
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            f1:e0:c2:3f:00:00:00:00
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = US, O = Cloud Services, OU = Operations, CN = SSL-SG1-GFRPA2
        Validity
            Not Before: Jan 31 00:00:00 2020 GMT
            Not After : Oct  9 12:00:00 2020 GMT
        Subject: C = US, ST = CA, L = San Francisco, O = "Cloudflare, Inc.", CN = sni.cloudflaressl.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                RSA Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:d8:31:07:5c:6d:c6:b3:4b:79:60:2f:87:14:39:
                    97:ca:0b:d1:ea:a2:a9:89:7a:2c:a6:11:16:aa:38:
                    0f:ac:11:11:96:da:ae:ab:27:7c:7f:6c:ff:bd:35:
                    67:29:a2:26:fa:85:96:1d:97:ff:b1:3e:ca:81:eb:
                    13:50:cd:55:f2:47:c2:ea:a4:c9:9c:5c:0e:3f:46:
                    9e:65:4a:a3:fb:58:3d:7b:de:1c:2e:a1:d2:82:66:
                    a4:6d:79:d6:23:8d:0e:cb:1c:80:4e:f9:99:8c:dc:
                    c1:84:e3:15:c5:0f:b2:e0:83:a4:78:a6:d3:76:b6:
                    07:85:ff:6f:ee:69:71:80:41:54:75:ee:2d:c6:68:
                    de:e3:87:87:13:88:1b:1e:bd:d0:14:b0:49:7e:90:
                    b6:b4:5f:c2:ff:ff:0b:fe:fe:a4:70:01:da:1f:8f:
                    5b:50:80:be:16:c6:8e:1a:b5:9e:e5:c2:9a:01:09:
                    10:6b:c2:2d:16:15:c3:cf:0d:a7:0c:e1:56:17:9e:
                    ca:bf:f6:db:dd:51:30:02:d9:b9:11:ca:6f:ac:ec:
                    ab:c0:a4:17:2b:8c:ad:60:4d:67:e4:a5:97:4d:b2:
                    e7:cc:06:59:89:2b:bf:77:9e:d2:44:5d:79:d6:38:
                    03:9f:fe:55:cb:fa:7b:0e:75:d4:5d:6c:e9:1e:f2:
                    b2:a7
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Key Usage: 
                Digital Signature, Non Repudiation, Key Encipherment
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:80:69:47:45:27:B6:26:29:03:06:1E:01:BC:42:A1:9C:DE:C1:94:A6

            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:conda.io, DNS:*.conda.io, DNS:sni.cloudflaressl.com
            Netscape Comment: 
                090560AE68F2769F04BBD27072BD6E3EJan 31 00:00:00 2020 GMTOct  9 12:00:00 2020 GMT
            X509v3 Certificate Policies: 
                Policy: X509v3 Any Policy
                  User Notice:
                    Explicit Text: 090560AE68F2769F04BBD27072BD6E3EJan 31 00:00:00 2020 GMTOct  9 12:00:00 2020 GMT

    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         13:92:fe:3e:d2:d5:35:5b:6e:5a:d3:97:24:ea:f3:92:fe:84:
         cb:da:0f:b0:77:e9:fc:29:75:3e:03:72:ad:5f:6d:49:98:c8:
         6d:15:90:19:13:31:5a:bc:98:01:0c:cb:33:cf:2f:b4:52:a7:
         73:e9:70:cc:5d:e4:12:0a:af:e0:71:15:20:cf:1c:fa:1a:3e:
         68:dc:7d:90:95:b6:b8:b9:54:51:e2:49:4a:80:43:3c:e2:b8:
         e6:98:db:28:57:72:28:e7:b3:cc:a3:25:80:00:11:1f:d7:8a:
         90:a3:97:a4:7a:67:95:91:9f:1d:22:18:ce:42:56:1b:80:e2:
         e1:75:34:8c:6f:02:b9:ff:04:13:86:ad:b0:31:bd:15:6f:1e:
         2d:11:21:82:45:57:0e:df:6e:9e:e0:98:af:b8:54:a4:7f:49:
         20:5a:b2:72:57:a8:55:00:8d:be:e4:3e:b3:90:6b:3c:d1:fc:
         a7:1b:2f:5a:b0:f6:c6:b8:f3:da:d9:05:9e:d4:4d:c3:be:05:
         36:c6:78:cc:d5:b8:e3:28:40:2f:02:0a:e4:d2:1b:be:69:9a:
         e3:f1:33:34:21:ce:39:3e:42:d7:f0:7d:5b:5c:5e:8b:aa:49:
         e7:80:07:dd:e1:80:2f:57:3b:c6:d4:22:55:6f:ad:10:e3:51:
         90:e6:c4:4b
```

**UPDATE2**

For /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt:

```
openssl x509 -noout -text < /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 6828503384748696800 (0x5ec3b7a6437fa4e0)
        Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: CN = ACCVRAIZ1, OU = PKIACCV, O = ACCV, C = ES
        Validity
            Not Before: May  5 09:37:37 2011 GMT
            Not After : Dec 31 09:37:37 2030 GMT
        Subject: CN = ACCVRAIZ1, OU = PKIACCV, O = ACCV, C = ES
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                RSA Public-Key: (4096 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:9b:a9:ab:bf:61:4a:97:af:2f:97:66:9a:74:5f:
                    d0:d9:96:fd:cf:e2:e4:66:ef:1f:1f:47:33:c2:44:
                    a3:df:9a:de:1f:b5:54:dd:15:7c:69:35:11:6f:bb:
                    c8:0c:8e:6a:18:1e:d8:8f:d9:16:bc:10:48:36:5c:
                    f0:63:b3:90:5a:5c:24:37:d7:a3:d6:cb:09:71:b9:
                    f1:01:72:84:b0:7d:db:4d:80:cd:fc:d3:6f:c9:f8:
                    da:b6:0e:82:d2:45:85:a8:1b:68:a8:3d:e8:f4:44:
                    6c:bd:a1:c2:cb:03:be:8c:3e:13:00:84:df:4a:48:
                    c0:e3:22:0a:e8:e9:37:a7:18:4c:b1:09:0d:23:56:
                    7f:04:4d:d9:17:84:18:a5:c8:da:40:94:73:eb:ce:
                    0e:57:3c:03:81:3a:9d:0a:a1:57:43:69:ac:57:6d:
                    79:90:78:e5:b5:b4:3b:d8:bc:4c:8d:28:a1:a7:a3:
                    a7:ba:02:4e:25:d1:2a:ae:ed:ae:03:22:b8:6b:20:
                    0f:30:28:54:95:7f:e0:ee:ce:0a:66:9d:d1:40:2d:
                    6e:22:af:9d:1a:c1:05:19:d2:6f:c0:f2:9f:f8:7b:
                    b3:02:42:fb:50:a9:1d:2d:93:0f:23:ab:c6:c1:0f:
                    92:ff:d0:a2:15:f5:53:09:71:1c:ff:45:13:84:e6:
                    26:5e:f8:e0:88:1c:0a:fc:16:b6:a8:73:06:b8:f0:
                    63:84:02:a0:c6:5a:ec:e7:74:df:70:ae:a3:83:25:
                    ea:d6:c7:97:87:93:a7:c6:8a:8a:33:97:60:37:10:
                    3e:97:3e:6e:29:15:d6:a1:0f:d1:88:2c:12:9f:6f:
                    aa:a4:c6:42:eb:41:a2:e3:95:43:d3:01:85:6d:8e:
                    bb:3b:f3:23:36:c7:fe:3b:e0:a1:25:07:48:ab:c9:
                    89:74:ff:08:8f:80:bf:c0:96:65:f3:ee:ec:4b:68:
                    bd:9d:88:c3:31:b3:40:f1:e8:cf:f6:38:bb:9c:e4:
                    d1:7f:d4:e5:58:9b:7c:fa:d4:f3:0e:9b:75:91:e4:
                    ba:52:2e:19:7e:d1:f5:cd:5a:19:fc:ba:06:f6:fb:
                    52:a8:4b:99:04:dd:f8:f9:b4:8b:50:a3:4e:62:89:
                    f0:87:24:fa:83:42:c1:87:fa:d5:2d:29:2a:5a:71:
                    7a:64:6a:d7:27:60:63:0d:db:ce:49:f5:8d:1f:90:
                    89:32:17:f8:73:43:b8:d2:5a:93:86:61:d6:e1:75:
                    0a:ea:79:66:76:88:4f:71:eb:04:25:d6:0a:5a:7a:
                    93:e5:b9:4b:17:40:0f:b1:b6:b9:f5:de:4f:dc:e0:
                    b3:ac:3b:11:70:60:84:4a:43:6e:99:20:c0:29:71:
                    0a:c0:65
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            Authority Information Access: 
                CA Issuers - URI:http://www.accv.es/fileadmin/Archivos/certificados/raizaccv1.crt
                OCSP - URI:http://ocsp.accv.es

            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                D2:87:B4:E3:DF:37:27:93:55:F6:56:EA:81:E5:36:CC:8C:1E:3F:BD
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:D2:87:B4:E3:DF:37:27:93:55:F6:56:EA:81:E5:36:CC:8C:1E:3F:BD

            X509v3 Certificate Policies: 
                Policy: X509v3 Any Policy
                  User Notice:
                    Explicit Text: 
                  CPS: http://www.accv.es/legislacion_c.htm

            X509v3 CRL Distribution Points: 

                Full Name:
                  URI:http://www.accv.es/fileadmin/Archivos/certificados/raizaccv1_der.crl

            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                email:accv@accv.es
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
         97:31:02:9f:e7:fd:43:67:48:44:14:e4:29:87:ed:4c:28:66:
         d0:8f:35:da:4d:61:b7:4a:97:4d:b5:db:90:e0:05:2e:0e:c6:
         79:d0:f2:97:69:0f:bd:04:47:d9:be:db:b5:29:da:9b:d9:ae:
         a9:99:d5:d3:3c:30:93:f5:8d:a1:a8:fc:06:8d:44:f4:ca:16:
         95:7c:33:dc:62:8b:a8:37:f8:27:d8:09:2d:1b:ef:c8:14:27:
         20:a9:64:44:ff:2e:d6:75:aa:6c:4d:60:40:19:49:43:54:63:
         da:e2:cc:ba:66:e5:4f:44:7a:5b:d9:6a:81:2b:40:d5:7f:f9:
         01:27:58:2c:c8:ed:48:91:7c:3f:a6:00:cf:c4:29:73:11:36:
         de:86:19:3e:9d:ee:19:8a:1b:d5:b0:ed:8e:3d:9c:2a:c0:0d:
         d8:3d:66:e3:3c:0d:bd:d5:94:5c:e2:e2:a7:35:1b:04:00:f6:
         3f:5a:8d:ea:43:bd:5f:89:1d:a9:c1:b0:cc:99:e2:4d:00:0a:
         da:c9:27:5b:e7:13:90:5c:e4:f5:33:a2:55:6d:dc:e0:09:4d:
         2f:b1:26:5b:27:75:00:09:c4:62:77:29:08:5f:9e:59:ac:b6:
         7e:ad:9f:54:30:22:03:c1:1e:71:64:fe:f9:38:0a:96:18:dd:
         02:14:ac:23:cb:06:1c:1e:a4:7d:8d:0d:de:27:41:e8:ad:da:
         15:b7:b0:23:dd:2b:a8:d3:da:25:87:ed:e8:55:44:4d:88:f4:
         36:7e:84:9a:78:ac:f7:0e:56:49:0e:d6:33:25:d6:84:50:42:
         6c:20:12:1d:2a:d5:be:bc:f2:70:81:a4:70:60:be:05:b5:9b:
         9e:04:44:be:61:23:ac:e9:a5:24:8c:11:80:94:5a:a2:a2:b9:
         49:d2:c1:dc:d1:a7:ed:31:11:2c:9e:19:a6:ee:e1:55:e1:c0:
         ea:cf:0d:84:e4:17:b7:a2:7c:a5:de:55:25:06:ee:cc:c0:87:
         5c:40:da:cc:95:3f:55:e0:35:c7:b8:84:be:b4:5d:cd:7a:83:
         01:72:ee:87:e6:5f:1d:ae:b5:85:c6:26:df:e6:c1:9a:e9:1e:
         02:47:9f:2a:a8:6d:a9:5b:cf:ec:45:77:7f:98:27:9a:32:5d:
         2a:e3:84:ee:c5:98:66:2f:96:20:1d:dd:d8:c3:27:d7:b0:f9:
         fe:d9:7d:cd:d0:9f:8f:0b:14:58:51:9f:2f:8b:c3:38:2d:de:
         e8:8f:d6:8d:87:a4:f5:56:43:16:99:2c:f4:a4:56:b4:34:b8:
         61:37:c9:c2:58:80:1b:a0:97:a1:fc:59:8d:e9:11:f6:d1:0f:
         4b:55:34:46:2a:8b:86:3b
```

Both of these works:

```
wget --ca-certificates=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/4.6.0/_downloads/52a95608c49671267e40c689e0bc00ca/conda-cheatsheet.pdf

wget --ca-certificates=conda1.crt https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/4.6.0/_downloads/52a95608c49671267e40c689e0bc00ca/conda-cheatsheet.pdf
```

**UPDATE3**
Regarding VM network setting:
[image]

**Part of the cause is found**

Bluecoat service which intercepts the network is the root cause (it has problem to VM Ubuntu only though, the host machine windows works fine with ssl).

However, I have not figured out how to solve this Bluecoat problem. Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: What are the subject/issuer fields of each certificate? This looks completely different from the certificate chain visible for `docs.conda.io` from any other location (which is DigiCert/CloudFlare).

Comment: @user1686 Thanks. The name `conda1.crt` is named by myself. Does the name matter?

Comment: No, the file name is not used for anything. I was asking about the certificates' "Subject" and "Issuer" fields. (See `certtool -i < conda1.crt` or `openssl x509 -noout -text < conda1.crt`.)

Comment: @user1686 THanks. I updated in the answer

Comment: After doing your changes, does wget still report exactly the same message or has its wording changed? If your system has the `trust` command, does `trust list | grep Cloud` find any results?

Comment: I repeat the recommendation I made on your earlier Q: try `openssl s_client -connect docs.conda.io:443 -showcerts`. (Ubuntu 18.04 has OpenSSL 1.1.1 so you no longer need `-servername x`.) That should use the same truststore as wget, so first check it gets the (equivalent) error, and if so see what details it gives about the error. PS: `x509` of `ca-certificates.crt` is not useful because it displays only the first cert in the file, which contains probably hundreds, and the one we care about is not first.

Comment: As I remember a bug we faced recently, could you verify that 1. besides the expected symlinks in `/etc/ssl/certs/` there are as well 8-bit hexadecimal named symlinks (`xxxxxxxx.0`) pointing to the expected symlinks and 2. there is no such pointing to your `conda[1-4].pem` symlinks?

Answer (score 0):

When SSL interception is enabled, the Bluecoat proxy will present spoofed
SSL certificates signed by itself to users when navigating to HTTPS sites.

Since those spoofed certificates are signed by the company Root CA,
users should trust in that Root CA which was probably installed for you
in Windows by the domain administrator.

The problem might be that this certificate is not installed in the VM, so this
is the base problem here. Installing it might fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks. As mentioned in the question description, I have installed the certificate (the cert has been validated to be the right one by running `wget --ca-certificates=conda1.crt https://...` ) in the VM.

Comment: Is the VM defined with NAT networking?

Comment: See attached the screenshot

Comment: It's NAT, so the VM communicates directly through Bluecoat. Is the problem unique to wget or does internet not work at all in the VM? Have you tried to use http rather than https to disable SSL intercept?

Comment: ... Note that the wget certificates folder is specified in `/etc/wgetrc` parameter `ca_certificate`.

Comment: Thanks. It's specific to https in VM for some sites, not all. Http has no problem since it does not require certificates. Not only `wget` has the problem, other tools like browser, `constall search`, `curl`, python code, etc. also have the problem

Comment: You don't get the problem on any browser?

Comment: Yes, other tools also have the problem, including browser, constall search, curl, python code, etc.

Comment: Did you examine `/etc/wgetrc`?

Comment: I'm asking that in the idea that each if these tools need special handling.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to add conda1.crt to your system to fix this.
The other certificates conda2.crt to conda4.crt are not needed.

Here is why:

In general when accessing a https website (and also conda.io) you always have 3 certificates in the chain.

- conda2.crt: Certificate of the root CA. This certificate is signed by itself.
- conda3.crt: Intermediate certificate. This certificate is signed by previous certificate.
- conda4.crt: End-user certificate. This certificate is signed by previous certificate.

As you can see the OS only needs the conda2.crt to see whether the following certificates are valid (because of the signature).
Because Ubuntu has all necessary root certificates installed by default, it's clear to see that you don't need to install these 3 certificates.

Now what BlueCoat does is to add another root certificate at the beginning of the chain (conda1.crt).
This is quite unusual because now you have 2 root certificates. Also it's no longer a "chain" because conda2.crt is not signed by conda1.crt.

I wonder this works at all! Maybe it's common practice for web washers.

As you can see, all you have to do is to add conda1.crt to your root certificates.

Of course someone might ask why the BlueCoat root certificate is not installed by default :-)

I have this assumption:

When you install BlueCoat it creates a root certificate with private and public key. So every BlueCoat installation has it's own root certificate.

**So to actually fix your problem**:

Please undo all your changes and follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73287/how-do-i-install-a-root-certificate) guide to only add conda1.crt.

Comment: While the information about the certificate chain and how it works is very useful in general, your answer cannot include the solution. Review the question and see that `conda1.crt` has been installed (matching the guide you linked) and verified valid already. I only mention it since your answer clearly states that it will "fix" the problem ;).

Comment: Yes you are right. He must have done something wrong when installing the certificate.

Answer (score 0):

If adding any certificate to local truststore with the mentioned usual methods (`update-ca-certificates`/`dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates`) fails to solve the handshake issue, the following might help:

1. Verify that a symlink is created in `/etc/ssl/certs/`, like:

   ```
   conda1.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/conda1.crt
   ```

   - This was true in your case, but I mention it for completeness.
2. Verify that `/etc/ssl/certs/` generally contains as well hash-named symlinks, pointing to every `.pem` symlink, like:

   ```
   b66938e9.0 -> Secure_Global_CA.pem
   ```
3. Verify that such a symlink exists as well for your `conda1.pem`, like:

   ```
   HHHHHHHH.0 -> conda1.pem
   ```
4. If it is missing, try the following ([man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/c_rehash)):

   ```
   c_rehash
   ```

**Background:**

- Some programs check for certificates only via their hash value, hence require those symlinks to find them.
- `update-ca-certificates` and `dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates` in some versions call `openssl rehash` to create those symlinks, but we observed that in some cases or with some versions `openssl rehash` does not do what it should.
- `c_rehash` is a dedicated script which *should* be equivalent to `openssl rehash` but in our case the first successfully created the symlinks while the latter failed to do so.
- We didn't further investigate the issue since it did not occur anymore after another OpenSSL package upgrade, but generally keeping those hash symlinks in mind is what we got from this issue.